# What does this mean? TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

Tags: python, atom-editor

is there anything wrong with my code? When i run my other if statements, the code works fine. But when i try to run this code, I keep getting some form of error.

```py
elif (0 < count < 3) and (account_balance > 50000) and (total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[0]):
    annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_2_categories_or_more_rates[0]
    annual_interest_rate2 = next_50k_3_categories_or_more_rates[0]

# another code

if account_balance > 50000:
        print(f'Interest rate applicable for the first S$50,000 is: {annual_interest_rate1:.2f}%')
        print(f'Interest rate applicable for the next S$50,000 is: {annual_interest_rate2:.2f}%')
```

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.**format**

NameError: name 'annual_interest_rate1' is not defined (i don't get this when i run the other lines of code)

Comment: Does your code enters the elif where the variables are being set ?

Comment: what do you mean? are you asking if i said annual_interest_rate1 = ......

Comment: The first lines of code you provide are a elif. I don't know if those code lines are executed before trying to access the annual interest rate 1. This could give you the name error.

Comment: i edited the code here. maybe this will help you

Comment: Don't you want to use loops to avoid repeating the same operation for each index in your arrays ? Can you print the two variables and give us the output just before the "another code" to see what this big if bings you back before bugging ?

Comment: i am actually not very sure about using loops as im a beginner in python. do you mind telling me how? that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your `TypeError` suggests that one of your `annual_interest_rateX` variables isn't the single number you expect, but instead a tuple of values. I don't know where the values are coming from, so I can't really tell you how fix it. Perhaps you need to index another layer deep or something.

As for the `NameError`, that means the variable isn't being defined at all. Probably that's because you're defining them in an `elif` block, but if you don't go into that branch (perhaps because you took an earlier `if`), you won't ever define the variables. You need to either make sure the variable always gets defined (in every branch), or that you don't access it if it won't exist (by rechecking the same conditions as the earlier `if`/`elif` perhaps).

Comment: hi, could you explain your second part?

Comment: Hmm, you've included more code now, so it does look like you cover all the cases in some branch. But it's not clear how the two different parts of your code interrelate. Are they both top level code, like you show, or are one or both parts in a function? Can you give the full traceback of your exceptions?

Comment: both are separate but i need to use the first code to get the interest rate then i can display/print which interest rate is applicable to each case. later on, i will proceed to compute the monthly interest earned. hope this answers your question.

Comment: Is either part of your code in a function? Because local variables in one function aren't visible outside of it. In any case, you should really post the traceback of your exception or exceptions. I'm not really sure why you have two different ones. Are you getting different errors in different runs?

Comment: only error when i try to run for this part:                                                            elif (0 < count < 3) and (account_balance > 50000) and (total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[0]):
    annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_2_categories_or_more_rates[0]
    annual_interest_rate2 = next_50k_3_categories_or_more_rates[0]

Comment: it's ok i managed to figure it out. thanks for all of your help:)